# monotouch this.NavigationController returns null for iPad

Tags: xamarin.ios

For my Universal Application
While running on iPad this.NavigationController returns me a NavigationController.

When I run it iPad targeted it is null. So I can't use it.

It's Initial view Controller.

Comment: This is a bit confusing, are you talking about the default templates that are provided by MonoDevelop / Xamarin.Studio ? If so there's many can you describe exactly which one is used (in both case).

Comment: I opened a new Universal application. In my StoryBoard I put a NaviationContoller as initial it redirects to login screen. Login.cs is a common Controller this.NavigationController is null for iPad only.

Answer (score 0):

Its my mistake,

For iPad design I used push RootNavigationController to Login.

It would be RelationShip.

Sorry for stealing your time friends.